# Почему цикл while(print()) в питоне не бесконечен?

Tags: python, while

В C++ например можно написать `while(std::cout<<"");`, и он будет бесконечным
В питоне же `while(print(" ")): pass` выполняется только 1 раз

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Просто потому, что питоновская функция `print()`, вызванная с любыми аргументами, всегда возвращает `None`, а значение `None` расценивается `while` как `False`.

Но, что забавно, вы можете обернуть `print` в кортеж и вот он то уже не будет восприниматься как `False`, поскольку он не совсем пустой - в нём есть `None` (т.е. получится кортеж `(None,)`, спасибо gil9red за уточнение):

```
while (print(" "),): pass
```

Я всего лишь добавил к вашему коду запятую в нужном месте, благо скобки (вообще-то не нужные для условия `while` в питоне) вы уже написали вокруг `print` сами.

Comment: Потому что, получится кортеж `(None,)` а он не будет пустым :)

Comment: @gil9red О, точно - кортеж. Всё время забываю, "как это будет по-русски" ))

Answer (score 3):

`while` работает с типом `bool`, для этого он вызывает магический метод `__bool__`. Это можно проверить так:

```
class MyClass:
    def __bool__(self):
        print("Bool")
        
        return False

while MyClass():
    pass
```

напечатается один раз `bool` и цикл прекратится т.к. мы вернули `False`. Если вернуть `True` то получится бесконечный цикл и вывод `Bool`

Если у класса отсутствует метод `__bool__` то будет использоваться метод `__len__`

```
class MyClass:
    def __len__(self):
        print("Len")
        
        return False

while MyClass():
    pass
```

Если у функции отсутствует `return` или после него ничего не написано, то возвращается `None`. Функции `print` всегда возвращает `None`, а при превращении его в `bool` он всегда будет `False`

```
print(bool(None)) # False
```

и поэтому в `while` попадает `False` и он сразу заканчивается

Есть такой тип данных как кортеж, он создаётся также и список но место квадратных нужно использовать круглые

```
a = (0, 1)
print(type(a)) # <class 'tuple'>
```

но чтобы создать кортеж из одного элемента надо писать так:

```
a = (0, )
print(type(a)) # <class 'tuple'>
```

т.е. надо добавить в запятую в конец, если его не записать то получится не кортеж:

```
a = (0)
print(type(a)) # <class 'int'>
```

в вашем случае скобки в `while` лишние, но если добавить запятую то мы получим кортеж длиной в один элемент

```
a = (print(" "), )
print(type(a)) # <class 'tuple'>
```

в цикле `while` у кортежа вызывается метод `__len__`. В вашем случае в кортеже лежит один элемент, и поэтому `__len__` возвращает `1`, которой при превращении в `bool` возвращает `True` и цикл становится бесконечным

Answer (score 2):

Если Вам нужен бесконечный цикл то это просто -

```
while True:
    print(" ")
```

И как бы всё `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: с чего вы взяли что автору нужен бесконечный цикл?

Comment: А кто сказал что Python это C++?